# wagtail AttributeError at /

Tags: wagtail

My project tree:
[image]

home_page.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}
Treichle-Cup
{% endblock %}
{% block body_class %}template-homepage{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

team_rooster.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  {% for team in teams %}
  <div class="row">
    <table border="2" width="100%">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="5">{{team.team_name}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">{{team.team_logo}}</td>
          <th colspan="3">Staff</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{{team.staff.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**It's hard to find out how wagtail view functionality works. My goal is just to render my team_rooster.html if i go to www.mysite.com/team-rooster**

i get an attributeerrof when i try to render my template

here is a traceback log
http://dpaste.com/3TH3WT5

```
{% load static wagtailcore_tags %}

  <div class="left-side sticky-left-side">
    <div class="logo-icon text-center custom-nav">
      <a href="{% pageurl team_rooster %}"><i class="fa fa-group fa-2x"></i></a>
      <span style="top: 76px">Teams</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

i tried with {% pageurl page.team_rooster %} but got same error

My model has following classes

```
class Staff(StructBlock):
    photo = ImageChooserBlock(required=False)
    position = ChoiceBlock(choices=[
        ('headcouch', 'Headcouch'),
        ], icon='cup')

    class Meta:
        icon = 'plus'

class Spieler(StructBlock):
    photo = ImageChooserBlock(required=False)
    position = ChoiceBlock(choices=[
        ('th', 'TH'),
        ], icon='cup')
    jahrgang = IntegerBlock(required=True)

    class Meta:
        icon = 'user'

class TeamRooster(Page):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    staff = StreamField([
        ('staff', CardsBlock(Staff(), icon="plus")),
    ], blank=True)
    spieler = StreamField([
        ('spieler', CardsBlock(Spieler(), icon="user")),
    ], blank=True)    

    content_panels = [
        FieldPanel('team_name', classname="col12"),
        ImageChooserPanel('team_logo'),
        StreamFieldPanel('staff'),
        StreamFieldPanel('spieler'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name
```

Comment: Just asking - is it meant to be ‘team_roster’ not ‘team_rooster’. Otherwise could you update the question with your page model?

Comment: yeah template name is team_rooster.html

Comment: OK. Could you update the question with the page model for the class `TeamRooster`? The error says `'str' object has no attribute 'relative_url'` which means that the `team_rooster` attribute on the current page is not a Page but just a string.

Comment: updated @lb-ben-johnston

Comment: Hopefully that answer helps (below), it appears you are just trying to get the URL of the page from within the template of that page. `self.team_rooster` in this case is not returning anything useful, most likely it is just the class name of the page. Comment me if that is not the issue.

Comment: to answer the question we still need more information - it is unclear what page you are trying to get the URL for. You mentioned below that 'pageurl self' loads the home page but mentioned above that this template is for a team_rooster page. Maybe confirm that the template code above is for which page and also add the HomePage model code.

Comment: Sorry. It is stil unclear what self.team_rooster is. If your HomePage model is just a simple Page then there will be no team_rooster attribute at all available from within the home_page.html template. What is in the home_page.html template? Are you using an include for the team_rooster.html maybe or is there some 'with' context?

Comment: i've updated the question @LBBenJohnston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the URL of the current page from within its own template simply do:

`{% pageurl self %}`

OR

`{% pageurl page %}`

Note: You must have loaded the `wagtailcore_tags` eg. `{% load wagtailcore_tags %}`

Comment: it works, but then it loads for me my home page template not my team_rooster template. Out of the box wagtail have home app where i have class HomePage(Page) model.

Comment: my HomePage model is just clear `class HomePage(Page):
    pass`